# How to inject specific dependency using constructor injection in an abstract class?

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

I have an `abstract` class which has below constructor -

```java
abstract class AbstractA<T> {
    protected CrudRepository<T, Long> crudRepository;  
    AbstractA(CrudRepository crudRepository) {
        this.crudRepository = crudRepository;
    }
}

abstract class AbstractB extend AbstractA<TableB> {
    protected Service service;
    // I want to autowire ConcreteCrudReposity here, but get myService from  
    //  subclass which is not a spring service.
    @Autowired 
    AbstractB(
        ConcreteCrudRepository<TableB, Long> concreteCrudRepository,
        MyService myService) {
        super(concreteCrudRepository);
    } 
}
class  AB extend AbstractB {
    AB() {
        super(new MyService()); // I know this is lame
    }
}
```

I want to inject a spring service in abstract class AbstractB using constructor injection but the other service (MyService) needs to come from the subclass which is not a spring service.

I know I can `@Autowire` the dependency in the child class but is it possible to do it in `AbstractB` because this dependency should really be injected from `AbstractB` (see the Generic entity type). And I only have constructor injection as an option. Note that I am using generics and there is much more code which I did not show to keep question simple.

Comment: Just as with a normal java you simply cannot do this. You will need to pass in all the dependencies into the constructor by calling super. Else it will not work.

Answer (score 0):

you can autowire to concrete class, and call super constructor with the arguments

```
    @Component
    class  AB extend AbstractB {
    @Autowired 
         AB(ConcreteCrudRepository concreteCrudRepository) {
            super(concreteCrudRepository, new MyService()); // I know this is lame
        }
    }
```

Comment: That's right but the problem is that `ConcreteCrudRepository` really belongs to `AbstractB` and there are many subclasses like `AB` and I don't want to inject the spring dependency from all the subclasses.

Answer (score 0):

A bit of a hack around is to use *field-injection* in the super `class`:

```
abstract class AbstractA {
    @Autowired
    protected CrudRepository crudRepository; 
}
```

Or *setter-injection*, which is cleaner and easier to test:

```
abstract class AbstractA {
    protected CrudRepository crudRepository;

    @Autowired
    protected void setCrudRepository(CrudRepository crudRepository) {
        this.crudRepository = crudRepository;
    }
}
```

As far as I know, this can be applied to as many classes in the hierarchy as possible.

Answer (score 0):

In java you have to provide a constructor "matching super" as compiler says. Leave alone the spring, if you don't do it in java - it won't even compile.

So assuming you've defined abstract classes with a constructors in the question, you merely don't have a choice but define the concrete class like this:

```
 @Component
    class  AB extend AbstractB {
         @Autowired // putting autowired is not mandatory, btw as long as you have a single constructor in descent spring versions
         AB(ConcreteCrudRepository concreteCrudRepository, Service service) {
            super(concreteCrudRepository, service);
        }
    }
```

Allocating the Service with `new` in the constructor will work from java standpoint (will compile and run), but you've said by yourself that it should be managed by spring, and obviously when you use `new` like this, spring will know nothing about this service, for example, if `MyService` has dependencies on its own, they won't be injected.

Let me also refer to your comment:

> the problem is that ConcreteCrudRepository really belongs to AbstractB

You basically work with a concrete class `AB` and not with an abstract class - in Java you can't instantiate an abstract class at all. This `AB` maintains the state: the service and the repository. Its true that technically its written in a way that it "borrows" the code from the super-class, but I suggest to think that you work with aт "independent" class.

The last point is about numerous classes like `AB`:

As long as spring manages them all (subclasses like `AB`, the Service and the repository), it should not be an issue:

Spring should be "clever enough" to resolve the dependencies like this and inject whatever needed as long as, again, it manages, all these sub-classes: the "magic" of injection can happen only with classes that are managed by spring itself.

Its true that if you need to add a "hint" to spring about what exactly should be injected, you can use techniques like `@Qualifier` but its already a different story.